# Visual Studio - Is there simple way to add 'Close Solution" to r-click in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I can't seem to break the habit of always right clicking on the solution to try and close a solution. Then I always remember and take my mouse the great distance across the screen to find it in the File menu.

I don't use it enough to remember a keystroke.

I use VS2008, VS2010 and occasionally VS2012

I'd prefer not to build an addin just for this small task.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can:

1. Right click on the Tool menu and click "Customize..".
2. Click the "Commands" tab.
3. Click the "Context menu" option.
4. Select the "Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution".
5. Click the "Add Command..." button.
6. Select "File" in the "Categories" list box.
7. Select "Close Solution" in the "Commands" list box.
8. Move up/down as desired.
9. Click "Close" and enjoy.

I don't have VS 2008 or 2012 handy, but the steps should be similar.

Edit: For VS2008

1. Right click on the Tool menu and click "Customize..".
2. Click the "Toolbars" tab.
3. Check the "Context menu" option. (the Context Menus tool bar will appear)
4. Select Command Tab in the current dialog.
5. Select "File" in the "Categories" list box.
6. Select "Close Solution" in the "Commands" list box.
7. Drag the Command to the "Select the "Project and Solution Context Menus" in the context Menus toolbar. You can drop it anywhere on the menu or in a sub menu - ie "Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution"
8. Click "Close" and enjoy.

Comment: I never knew that customise context existed! I've added the slightly different way to do it for VS2008. Thanks tonnes mate!

Comment: I also didn't know this existed. A bit of advice to anyone trying to follow thse instructions. You can click anywhere in the menu or toolbar area, it doesn't have to be the Tools menu. Also, I saw "Solution Folder" & thought that must have been what the OP meant, but of course discovered that the command didn't show where it should have. "Solution" is actually a bit further down in the list. Once I made the correct selection, it worked perfectly. It's given me all sorts of ideas now. So THANKS!

Comment: @CodeNaked I have done the same thing for Close Project under  "Project and Solution Context Menus | Project". When I right click the project I could see the Close project in a disabled mode. Unable to select the Close project.

Answer (score 1):

***VISUAL STUDIO 2019***

Here is the way to do this with **COMBINATION KEYS**, that it is so better than add it to toolbar or context menu :)

1. Go to **Tools** menu
2. Go to **Options**
3. Press **Ctrl+E** and search Keyboard // OR go to
   **Environment>Keyboard**
4. In right side type **CLOSE** in **search bar**(below of **"Show
   commands containing"** I mean)
5. Go down and select the **"File.CloseSolution"** from the results
6. Click on the box **"Press shortcuts keys:"** and specify your
   combination's key
7. **Be aware** that Visual Studio has a lot of **default** combination keys and **do not use any regular shortcut**.( I used **Ctrl+F4**)
8. Check the "Use new shortcut in:" and select your place that want to
   use this shortcut (I suggest to use **GLOBAL**)
9. Click **Assign** > **OK** > **Have Fun**

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You can close the solution by simply clicking File->Close Solution in Visual Studio 2017

[image: Close Solution]

Comment: I specifically asked that I didn't want to use this method